# MySQL Pivot View Dynamic

Tags: mysql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like

```html
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| warehouse                         | item_code                                 | stock_value |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 103-VAN DXB- U56403 NADEEM - DLTL | Alcatel 1054D 1054E BLACK CHARCOAL GREY   | 500         |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 103-VAN DXB- U56403 NADEEM - DLTL | Alcatel 1054D 1054E BLACK+PURE WHITE      | 15000       |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 100-Main Warehouse - Nahda - DLTL | Alcatel 2008D WHITE+METAL SILVER DUAL SIM | 45643       |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 100-Main Warehouse - Nahda - DLTL | Alcatel 2008D-BLACK METAL SILVER DUAL SIM | 4544        |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4fe92/1/0

The column warehouse name is not fixed. So how I can create a Pivot table like below

```html
+-------------------------------------------+----------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
| item                                      | Main Warehouse | NADEEM | total quantity | total value |
+-------------------------------------------+----------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
| Alcatel 1054D 1054E BLACK CHARCOAL GREY   | 0              | 1      | 1              | 500         |
+-------------------------------------------+----------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
| Alcatel 1054D 1054E BLACK+PURE WHITE      | 0              | 1      | 1              | 1500        |
+-------------------------------------------+----------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
| Alcatel 2008D WHITE+METAL SILVER DUAL SIM | 1              | 0      | 1              | 45643       |
+-------------------------------------------+----------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
| Alcatel 2008D-BLACK METAL SILVER DUAL SIM | 1              | 0      | 1              | 4544        |
+-------------------------------------------+----------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse the data in the warehouse column to get the information needed for the Main Warehouse and NADEEM columns in your pivot report?

Comment: How many distinct warehouses must appear in your output result set? How do you convert the values of the `warehouse` column in your input table to the headings of the rows( `Main Warehouse`, `NADEEM`) in your desired output? Does the second row of your desired output have a mistake in the `total_value` column?  Please [edit] your question to provide more detail. Generating pivot results in MySQL is a notorious pain in the neck, just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it assuming you are going to parse the desired information out of your warehouse field:

```
SELECT item_code, 
  IF(LOCATE('Main Warehouse', warehouse), 1, 0) AS `Main Warehouse`, 
  IF(LOCATE('NADEEM', warehouse), 1, 0) AS `NADEEM`, 
  COUNT(item_code) AS total_quantity
FROM some_table
GROUP BY item_code
```